# Stop url encoding cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Consider the following ASP.net web api controller method. For demo purpose it returns a cookie. the session-id cookie has a base64 encoded data. When I add the cookie to the response with `response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });` it url encodes the data (Documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponseheadersextensions.addcookies%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)). Is there any way I can attach the cookie without encoding it?

```
  public HttpResponseMessage LogMeIn()
  {
     var response = Request.CreateResponse<Models.UserAuthResponse>(new Models.UserAuthResponse());

     var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session-id", "K2QRkQaSnwCBpRrAgI1K3w9kTgbArc+xdIJI64e2hz0=");
     cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
     cookie.Domain = ".example.com";
     cookie.Path = "/";
     response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
     return response;
  }
```

Comment: Why do you not want the cookie to be url encoded?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, keep in mind cookie is always transferred in request/response headers, and if you don't encode special characters, it will definitely mess up the header structure. Also whenever you are trying to read the cookie it will be automatically decoded, so I don't see any point to get around the encode.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem because i want to create LTPA Token cookie used by Lotus Domino SSO web applications and this cookie is base64 encoded and use special characters in cookie like `+=....`.

I've found three way to solve this problem:

1. OWIN extension in `Startup.cs`

   ```cs
   app.Use((context, next) =>
   {
       context.Response.Headers....;
       //here decode and replace the cookies
       return next.Invoke();
   });
   ```
2. Using JavaScript after page load with cookies:

   ```js
   document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
   ```
3. Or the best way is to create extension like this:

   ```cs
   /// <summary>
   ///
   /// </summary>
   public static class CookieExtensions
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Add a new cookie and value
       ///
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="header"></param>
       /// <param name="key"/><param name="value"/>
       public static void AppendUrlDecodedCookie(this IHeaderDictionary header, string key, string value)
       {
           header.AppendValues("Set-Cookie", key + "=" + value + "; path=/");
       }

       ///  <summary>
       ///  Add a new cookie
       ///
       ///  </summary>
       /// <param name="header"></param>
       /// <param name="key"/><param name="value"/><param name="options"/>
       public static void AppendUrlDecodedCookie(this IHeaderDictionary header, string key, string value, CookieOptions options)
       {
           if (options == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("options");
           bool flag1 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Domain);
           bool flag2 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Path);
           bool hasValue = options.Expires.HasValue;
           header.AppendValues("Set-Cookie",
               key + "=" + (value ?? string.Empty) + (!flag1 ? (string) null : "; domain=") +
               (!flag1 ? (string) null : options.Domain) + (!flag2 ? (string) null : "; path=") +
               (!flag2 ? (string) null : options.Path) + (!hasValue ? (string) null : "; expires=") +
               (!hasValue
                   ? (string) null
                   : options.Expires.Value.ToString("ddd, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss ",
                       (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "GMT") +
               (!options.Secure ? (string) null : "; secure") + (!options.HttpOnly ? (string) null : "; HttpOnly"));
       }
   }
   ```

   And you can use it like this:

   ```cs
   response.Headers.AppendUrlDecodedCookie("key", "val");
   ```

   or

   ```cs
   response.Headers.AppendUrlDecodedCookie("key", "val", 
       new Microsoft.Owin.CookieOptions
           {
               Path = "/",
               Domain = ="domain.com",
               Expires = Date...
           });
   ```

And this solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I'm having the same problem and your third option is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Kestrel still seems to block it. Dont get how Microsoft cant have a flag to allow this for compatibility with systems that dont use .Net. SSO is out the window with this.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http IHeaderDictionary doesn't have AppendValues(...). With using Microsoft.Owin I get version 3 to compile, but obviously that is not a compatible extensinon to my AspNetCore Header...

Answer (score 4):

**In a NET Core project**, I did an extension method to HttpResponse. In my case, I needed to replace all space characters in order to have a valid cookie value. keep in mind what kind of values you need to save and then update the string properly before creating the setCookieHeaderValue .

```
    public static class CookiesExtensions
{
    public static void AppendUnencodedCookie(this HttpResponse response, string key, string value, CookieOptions options)
    {
        if (options == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
        }

        response.Cookies.Delete(key);

        var setCookieHeaderValue = new SetCookieHeaderValue(key, value.Replace(" ","+"))
        {
            Domain = options.Domain,
            Path = options.Path,
            Expires = options.Expires,
            MaxAge = options.MaxAge,
            Secure = options.Secure,
            SameSite = (Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.SameSiteMode)options.SameSite,
            HttpOnly = options.HttpOnly
        };

        response.Headers[HeaderNames.SetCookie] = StringValues.Concat(response.Headers[HeaderNames.SetCookie], setCookieHeaderValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Context.Response.AppendUnencodedCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, options);
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you.  I'm using your solution for writing multi-key cookies in ASP.NET Core, so that it does not encode the "=" and "&" symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Use headers to set your cookie value:

```
context.Response.Headers.AppendValues("Set-Cookie", "Key=Value; path=/");
```

Replace Key with your Cookie Key
and Value with desired value