# WebAPI encoding cookie values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am setting cookies on my ASP.Net web api controller. This is my code portion:

```
var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue(cookieName, cookieValue) 
{
    Expires = cookieExpires, Domain =cookieDomain,  Path= "/"
};
response.Headers.AddCookies(new[] {cookie});
```

I noticed the value of cookie is being automatically encoded. So `abc==` becomes `abc%3d%3d`. This doesn't happen on a regular MVC controller.

How do I prevent his encoding from happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428295/stop-url-encoding-cookie

Comment: CodeCaster. Thank you for your response. Yes, that person is having the same issue I am having. No successful response have been provided. Hopefully someone will provide a solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It's encoded because otherwise "abc==" string value would result to an invalid cookie. Encoding is automatic to prevent invalid characters like "=" to be present in the cookie.

I'm not sure what do you mean that it doesn't happend in MVC, maybe that when you access the cookie value in request then it's decoded?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie

**EDIT**
If "abc==" string is Base64 encoded byte array then you can get arround by using System.Web.HttpServerUtility UrlTokenEncode/UrlTokenDecode methods instead. Then no other encoding will occur.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
By MVC I mean a regular MVC controller. I basically have the same set of HttpCookies on both controllers: an MVC controller and a Web Api Controller. The MVC Controller doesn’t encode it and it works well. The Web Api Controller does encode it.

Comment: Could you please capture the responses with cookie being in Fiddler or similar tool and post them?

Comment: Sure. These are the responses. For the regular controller: **Set-Cookie: MyCookie=abc==; expires=Thu, 13 Aug 2015 18:41:31 GMT; domain=my.domain.com**
For the web api controller:
**Set-Cookie: MyCookie=abc%3d%3d; expires=Thu, 13 Aug 2015 18:41:31 GMT; domain=my.domain.com**

Comment: This is kind of old, but Wikipedia states that: "The name of a cookie excludes the same characters, as well as =, since that is the delimiter between the name and value". So, the '=' character is invalid for the cookie name, not its value.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent it pls use below, wherever you read cookies:

```
Server.UrlDecode("Your string");
```

It will remove that '%3d' and convert it back to '='