# Stop IResponseCookies.Append() from encoding cookies. dotnetcore 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, owin

We are building a dotnetcore 2.0 web app that receiving cookies from a legacy system via http and setting the cookies in the response.

When I debug the app I can see that `cookie.value` is not url encoded but after calling append the set-cookie headers are url encoded. This is problematic as the legacy cookies need to be unencoded as legacy apps read them as they are.

```
    public static void AddCookie(this IResponseCookies cookies, Cookie cookie)
    {
        cookies.Append(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, new CookieOptions
        {
            Domain = cookie.Domain,               
            Expires = cookie.Expires == DateTime.MinValue ? null : (DateTimeOffset?) cookie.Expires,
            HttpOnly = cookie.HttpOnly,
            Path = cookie.Path,
            Secure = cookie.Secure
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to prevent them being encoded? A flag or setting somewhere?

I tried writing an owin middleware but the set-cookie header is always empty.

```
public class CookieDecode
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CookieDecode(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var x = context.Response.Headers;
        var y = x["set-cookie"];
        //y is always empty
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no option to avoid the URL encoding.  However, [here is what `Append`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/6657f4cf36b1790b365f1c80e58c1eed39f8d11b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Internal/ResponseCookies.cs#L50) is doing.  Can you try manually setting the header the same way they do?

```
    public void Append(string key, string value, CookieOptions options)
    {
        if (options == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
        }

        var setCookieHeaderValue = new SetCookieHeaderValue(
            Uri.EscapeDataString(key),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(value))
        {
            Domain = options.Domain,
            Path = options.Path,
            Expires = options.Expires,
            MaxAge = options.MaxAge,
            Secure = options.Secure,
            SameSite = (Net.Http.Headers.SameSiteMode)options.SameSite,
            HttpOnly = options.HttpOnly
        };

        var cookieValue = setCookieHeaderValue.ToString();

        Headers[HeaderNames.SetCookie] = StringValues.Concat(Headers[HeaderNames.SetCookie], cookieValue);
    }
```

Comment: You could probably add an extension method too.  Just make it static, give it a new name, and take out the escapes.  The class is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.ResponseCookies`

Comment: This looked perfect however SetCookieHeaderValue throws an exception when passing it an unencoded value. But from your suggestion I found a similar solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428295/stop-url-encoding-cookie that doesn't use SetCookieHeaderValue so happy to give you the right answer.

Comment: @MarkVickery, that answer works for Web API. Because I don't see `AppendValues` method there. How did you solve that?

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli I just used header.Append("Set-Cookie"... instead.